# Managing data drift when using w2vec embeddings on VertexAI

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, word2vec, google-cloud-vertex-ai

So I am looking into moving my models from GCP's AI Platform to Vertex AI, my main motivation for it being the fact that Vertex AI has automatic email notifications when your data skews or drifts (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-monitoring/using-model-monitoring).

So if you start receiving dodgy data that doesn't resemble the training set, they send you an email telling you which features (columns) of the data you are trying to predict are drifting away from your training data.

However, I am unsure how this would work in my case since my data is text data that has been encoded using word2vec embeddings. Therefore, my dataset has 300 columns but I don't know what feature each of the columns refers to.

Is this sort of data drift analysis still useful in my particular case?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, you can let Google Cloud know that this is a feature important to your workflow, and that you would like to request they implement it. However, there is no ETA nor implementation guarantee for the said feature.

Comment: Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. I'd suggest you make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Vertex AI Model Monitoring](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1132251&template=1639153), with the `Feature Request` template.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, Vertex AI Model Monitoring supports feature skew and drift detection for [categorical and numerical features only](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-monitoring/overview#:%7E:text=Model%20Monitoring%20supports%20feature%20skew%20and%20drift%20detection%20for%20categorical%20and%20numerical%20features). As you said, the embeddings cannot be traced back to the actual data and the encodings themselves cannot be considered categorical nor numerical in this context.

> Is this sort of data drift analysis still useful in my particular case?

Yes, it would be useful to perform drift analysis. There are several ways to account for drifts in an NLP data set. You can take a look at this [blog](https://neptune.ai/blog/concept-drift-best-practices) for more information on tackling such drifts in NLP. Please note that this article is not officially supported by Google Cloud.